# I want delete cell of tableview which are empty and hidden as well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want delete cell of tableview in `iPhone` application which are empty and hidden as well. but space taken by those cells.we have used this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([cell isKindOfClass:[IASKPSTextFieldSpecifierViewCell class]])
    {
        UITextField *field = ((IASKPSTextFieldSpecifierViewCell*)cell).textField;
        [field setTextColor:LINPHONE_MAIN_COLOR];

    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // Background View
    UACellBackgroundView *selectedBackgroundView = [[[UACellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
      if (indexPath.section==1)
    {
        if (indexPath.row== 1)
        {
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            return cell;
        }


    }
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
         //NSLog(@"value is--%@",);
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Opus 48kHz"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"G.711U-law";
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Silk 24Khz"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"G.711A-law";
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Silk 16Khz"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"GSM";
        }
        if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"AAC-ELD 22kHz"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"iLBC30";
        }


        if (indexPath.row==6)
        {

            cell.hidden=YES;
           // cell=nil;
        }
        if (indexPath.row==7)
        {

            cell.hidden=YES;
            //cell=nil;
        }
        if (indexPath.row==8)
        {

            cell.hidden=YES;
            //cell=nil;
        }
        if (indexPath.row==9)
        {
            cell.hidden=YES;
            //cell=nil;
        }

        if (indexPath.row==10)
        {
            cell.hidden=YES;
            //cell=nil;
        }
        if (indexPath.row==11)
        {
            cell.hidden=YES;
            //cell=nil;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.hidden=YES;
          return cell;
    }

    self.tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor blackColor];
     return cell;

}
```

Comment: hahaha.. i also acknowledge you :)

Comment: Have you thought of creating a static tableview in the storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that data from your `tableArray` and then reload `table`, this will remove that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource must reflect what you need to show in table view, in cellForRowAtIndexPath you must configure (and alloc/init if needed) the cells, when a cell is not needed it will be automatically free by the table view.

P.S. the code you posted is OMG... O.O